# Hey i try to build a game in UWP(c#) and i cant make my player move

Tags: c#, uwp

i search in the internt and only found WPF tutorials to how make objects move and it is diffrent from UWP.

e.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up)

tried to do use this with if statment to change position of the object but coudlnt figure it out the keys doesnt work.do you an idea?Thanks

Comment: don't want to sound patronizing but you could test the keys by printing the current key pressed? 
- To make sure the stroke is actually being picked up, hope this helps

Comment: can you expalin?

Comment: you said the key doesnt work, so you need to determine if its the logic you have used or if is the incorrect method. There is a similar post here on detecting key inputs 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249029/uwp-keydown-event
https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/06/the-right-way-to-check-for-key-state-in-uwp-apps/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406898/detecting-keys-pressed-without-events-in-uwp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can use the CoreWindow.KeyDown event to handle keys:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
}

private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.VirtualKey)
    {
        case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Left:
            //Go left
            break;
        case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right:
            //Go right
            break;
        case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up:
            //Go up
            break;
        case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down:
            //Go down
            break;
    }


    //In case you want to check for Control + Key:
    var ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control);
    if (ctrl.HasFlag(Windows.UI.Core.CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down))
    {
        //Control was pressed

        if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.W)
        {
            //Do sprint
        }
    }
}
```